# Link in the app title in the Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I created a Facebook application linked to my android application with the Facebook SDK. I allow users to share images from my android application, but I really don't understand how to edit the link in the application title of the Facebook Post.

I mean:

[image: Example of application title]
If I click on the "Shazam", I will be redirected on the Shazam's web site. How to customize this link?

Comment: You don’t “customize” it. Whether it gets shown and where it points to, depends on what platforms you have set up for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to add the Web platform in the Developer Console, in which I  specified the link.